# python 3.5 using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I installed python 3.5 and it worked fine. Then I downloaded 
pymssql-2.1.1.win32-py3.4.exe (md5) 
from 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.1#downloads

During the installation it asked for python 3.4 installation and dimmed the Next button.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Python3.5 and then installed Python 3.4.3, after that pymssql installer passed through. I didn't realized the python version has to be exact match to the database driver version since I am new to Python.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) or [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) which uses the ODBC drivers installed on your machine which comes with SQL Server installs.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks,